# org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException while select/insert/delete concurrently

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

```
nested exception is org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException: could not execute
statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not execute statement] with root cause

org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.dao.QueryException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

I am getting the above Exception while trying to insert into mysql database from 2 separate instances of a Java application. Each of them is capable of making 10 concurrent inserts from 10 different workers and that is enough to cause this.

code which throws this:

```
@Autowired
org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;

void process(Long key) {
    boolean processed = transactionTemplate.execute(
        transactionStatus -> {
            acquireLock(key);
            try {
                return processOneRecord(key);
            }
            finally {
                releaseLock(key);
            }
        }
    );

acquireLock(key);
```

attempts to acquire a lock by inserting key into a lock table (only one column, which is key). This is done so that locking can be guaranteed across instances - table acts as a semaphore lock table

```
processOneRecord(key);
```

does something which can take a few milliseconds to seconds

```
releaseLock(key);
```

removes the lock using a delete statement

When we get the exception, we sleep for a certain millisecond and retries, nevertheless, deadlock situation persists.

How to solve this?

PS:

DBAs are not happy with the approach at all, so long-term solution is to avoid using the database for lock management (by leveraging a message queue). In the meantime, looking for a meaningful workaround

Comment: any scope of using spring transaction management ?